# Is there a way to prevent validation of input field with step attribute?

Tags: html

I have an input like this:

```
<input type="number" min="0" step="10">
```

I'm using the `step` attribute for more convenient way of using input arrow keys, but if I put something not divisible by 10, I have an validation error like this:
[image]

Is there a way to disable this validation, which is forced by the `step` attribute? Because I still want user could enter whatever positive integer he wants.

Comment: You'd have to create custom spinner buttons which increment the value by 10 on click. The `step` attribute defines the 'legal' multiples that can be used so there isn't  a way around it without JS